# Convert JSON with objects and arrays to String

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
    {
        files: ['test.mp4'],
        name: ['testFile'],
        hints: ['%YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%']
    }
```

And I need to convert it to a String so the output looks like this:

```
[{files=test, name=testFile, hints= %YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%}]
```

Is this possible to achieve in Node JS? Thanks

I tried the following:

```
var x = {
    files: ['test.mp4'],
    name: ['testFile'],
    hints: ['%YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%']
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

But the output looks like this:

```
{"files":["test.mp4"],"name":["testFile"],"hints":["%YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%"]}
```

Still with the square brackets. I may not 100% know the keys and values in the object above.

Comment: that is not a valid object

Comment: This is what I get returned in my GET response

Comment: did you try JSON.stringfy() ? It will convert and json object to a string.

Comment: **JSON is a string!** there is no such thing as a JSON object. There are only objects and a multitude of ways to represent them as strings/serialize them; one of them being the JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: `And I need to convert it to a String so the output looks like this: [{files=test, name=testFile, hints= %YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%}]` What format is that? And what are the rules to this serialization? For example, how would I serialize an array that contains two items like `{ files: ['test.mp4', 'test2.mp4'] }`? Or if the string itself contains structural characters like spaces, commas or brackets?

Answer (score 3):

Try 
`JSON.stringify(obj)`

then you get a string with quotes etc.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method which can convert an object into string:

```
var x = {
    files: ['test.mp4'],
    name: ['testFile'],
    hints: ['%YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%']
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
// result: '{"files":["test.mp4"],"name":["testFile"],"hints":["%YES%_%MAYBE%_%NO%"]}'
```

This will result in a string which can be transformed back to JS object with `JSON.parse()` method. If you still want to remove all brackets and quotes, you can simply use JavaScript's `replace()` method (replacing characters `[`, `]`, and `"` with empty string), but this will replace those characters in all your values (if any) and will result in (sort of) non-reusable string.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Don't do this unless you absolutely have to (ie. you're dealing with a messed up API written by someone else that must have the data in this format)

If you want exactly the format listed in your question, then you're going to have to write your own `stringify` function that recursively walks through the object you pass to it and applies whatever rules you want to use. You will have to consider all the possible permutations of your object and spell out those rules.

For example, you've converted arrays with single elements in the initial object into strings - what happens if there is more than one element in the array? Should it be delimited by a comma or some other character? Should we just throw away elements after the first?

And once you've written the `stringify` function, you'll also have to write the corresponding `parse` function to reverse it. And it should be mentioned that in your example, you're throwing away information (eg. the file extension on the `.mp4` file) - how are you going to handle that?

**A much, much better way** to approach this would be to do what other people have suggested here: **use `JSON.stringify`** and rewrite your code to use standard JSON objects. Why? Because the format is well documented and well understood and because the functions to convert are well tested. **You will save yourself a whole lot of time and pain if you don't try to reinvent the wheel here**.